# maven repo spring-security RC

Tags: maven-2, spring-security

can't find it anywhere:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

same with RC1. Does anyone now where to get it?
thanks

Comment: seems that one works: 
 <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=80366) or [this one](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=79034&highlight=maven), you'll find the **RC1** jars in springframework milestone repository:

```
...
<properties>
    .....
    <spring-security.version>3.0.0.RC1</spring-security.version>
</properties>
...
<repositories>
     ....
    <repository>
        <id>Springframework milestone</id>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
 </dependencies>
 ...
```

Of course, adapt it to suit your needs. Strangely, it doesn't contain RC2 jars. But if you need a more recent version, you'll find SNAPSHOTS in the repository below (I don't know if it has a "nice" alias) that you can browser through [s3browse.com](http://s3browse.com/explore/maven.springframework.org/snapshot/org/springframework):

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-maven-snapshot</id>
    <name>Springframework Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yes, but as i understood - s3 is only for browsing, and springframework.org/milestone - is for downloading. the thing that confused me - it's unable to browse this repo, but it contains all RCs.

Comment: My understanding is that spring use s3 for its maven repositories, http://maven.springframework.org/milestone, http://maven.springframework.org/release, http://maven.springframework.org/external are just aliases. You can browse milestone with s3browse http://s3browse.com/explore/maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/ (it doesn't contain RC2 as I wrote). You can use http://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.springframework.org/snapshot for downloading of SNAPSHOTS (as I wrote).